# onActivity result not working

Tags: android, android-activity

My activity class from which I am passing some result to another activity so that it can perform some different action

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(OrderDetails.this, AppointmentSchedulingActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("JobID", jobid);
                i.putExtra("Resultt","1");
                startActivityForResult(i,1);
            }
```

And my second activity where I am getting response from above activity in onActivity Result method using this onActivityResult code but this `onActivityResult` method is not firing

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1)
        {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                try {
                    continuee.setText("Reschedule");

                    continuee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            ListofAddressesDataModel selectedItem = ((ListofAddressesAdapter) add.getAdapter()).getSelectedItem();
                            String customeraddressid = selectedItem.getCustaddid();
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.VERIFICATION, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                            editor.putString(AppConstants.SELECTEDCUSTOMERADDRESSID, customeraddressid);
                            new reschedulejob().execute(jobid, customeraddressid, dateTxt, timeTxt);


                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {

                }
            }
        }

        else {

            continuee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppointmentSchedulingActivity.this, OrderSummary1.class);
                    ListofAddressesDataModel selectedItem = ((ListofAddressesAdapter) add.getAdapter()).getSelectedItem();
                    String name = selectedItem.getName();
                    String phone = selectedItem.getPhone();
                    String address = selectedItem.getFulladdress();
                    String customeraddressid = selectedItem.getCustaddid();
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.VERIFICATION, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.SELECTEDCUSTOMERNAME, name);
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.SELECTEDCUSTOMERPHONE, phone);
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.SELECTEDCUSTOMERADDRESS, address);
                    editor.putString(AppConstants.SELECTEDCUSTOMERADDRESSID, customeraddressid);
                    editor.commit();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

So I want to know why my onActivity result is not getting fired. I want two different actions to be performed on the continue button. Should I put this in onResume method? I just want 2 different actions to be performed here

[image]

Comment: Please check readyandroid answer. What you want to achieve in onActivityResult with continuee view?

Answer (score 1):

In the given code you are calling `startActivityForResult()` from the first class and you have your `onActivityResult()` in second class.

That is what you have written, so I am assuming that there are two different activities that implementing the above said methods. 
Please remember that `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` both methods have to be in the same activity.

If you don't know how to use startActivityForResult(), check this tutorial [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-startactivityforresult-example)

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

startActivityForResult(..) is used to get data back to the caller activity.

if you want to pass data then use startActivity(intent) and get it on the second activity onCreate() method.

first activity

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(OrderDetails.this, AppointmentSchedulingActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("JobID", jobid);
                i.putExtra("Resultt","1");
                startActivity(i);
            }
```

on the second activity

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.second_activity); 

    //extract the intent
     Intent intent = getIntent();
        String id = intent.getStringExtra("JobID");
        String result = intent.getStringExtra("Resultt");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you derived in your code that in the first activity you wrote a code for startActivityForResult and in the second activity you tried to get a result callback for second activity operation.

First of all, I want to tell you one thing that if you want to use startActivityForResult then your startActivityForResult code and onActivityResult code should be in same activity, means activity first from you are trying to start the second activity.
For more info check: [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

And second thing is you are trying to do some click event in onActivityResult callback in second activity(like: continuee.setOnClickListener), I think this continuee view is related to your second activity. So what you want to achieve here?